# Hide field form fields_view_get

Tags: odoo

```
def fields_view_get(self, cr, uid, view_id=None, view_type='form', context=None, toolbar=False, submenu=False): 

    #override of fields_view_get in order to change the label of the process button and the separator accordingly to the shipping type 

    if context is None: context={} 

    res = super(stock_partial_picking, self).fields_view_get(cr, uid, view_id=view_id, view_type=view_type, context=context, toolbar=toolbar, submenu=submenu) type = context.get('default_type', False) 

    if type: doc = etree.XML(res['arch']) 
        for node in doc.xpath("//button[@name='do_partial']"): 
             if type == 'in': 
                 node.set('string', _('_Receive')) 
             elif type == 'out': 
                 node.set('string', _('_Deliver'))
```

---

i want to hide qty,expire_date field

---

```
    for node in doc.xpath("//separator[@name='product_separator']"):
        if type == 'in':
            node.set('string', _('Receive Products'))
        elif type == 'out':
            node.set('string', _('Deliver Products'))
    res['arch'] = etree.tostring(doc)
return res
```

Comment: You should format it first.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `"invisible" = "1"`,

```
for node in doc.xpath("//separator[@name='product_separator']"):
        if type == 'in':
            node.set('string', _('Receive Products'))
            node.set('invisible', '1')
        elif type == 'out':
            node.set('string', _('Deliver Products'))
    res['arch'] = etree.tostring(doc)
return res
```

Comment: It doesn't work, at least in our OpenERP  6.1 system.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide a filed in a similar mannar as xml view, but you must use modify attribute like attrs.
Anyway the result let it be like this:
`<field name="fieldname" modifiers={'invisible': True} />`

(In my experience, if I want to take a condition to visibility, not working in fields_view_get)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

To hide the field from form view: using fields_view_get function

```
doc = etree.XML(res['arch'])
if show_hp_status: 
    for node in doc.xpath("//field[@name='status_1']"):
        #use either 'invisible' or node.remove
        node.set('invisible', '1')
        doc.remove(node)
else:
    for node in doc.xpath("//field[@name='status_2']"):
        #use either 'invisible' or node.remove
        node.set('invisible', '1')
        doc.remove(node)

res['arch'] = etree.tostring(doc)
```